# Laravel/Homestead configuration: update aliases

Tags: macos, bash, laravel

In the process of learning Laravel, I am following the tutorial *Build Larabook from scratch* (Laracast).

In the fist video, we are setting up everything, the narrator asks to update aliases with the following command:

```
sudo vi ~/.aliases
```

and explains:

> Just remember though, this file won't exist on your machine, so maybe
>   do Bash Profile.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given command simply open file `~/.aliases` by using vi editor. If you didn't create this file before, most probably it simply does not exists yet, so you need to create it.

To create it you can simply run these commands:

```
sudo touch ~/.aliases
sudo vi ~/.aliases
```

Or if you use some other text editor of preference you can run:

```
sudo pstorm ~/.aliases (for phpStorm IDE)
```

When the file is opened, simply paste there what the narrator tell you.